# How to create unit test for CellEditor component

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm learning Angular and Ag-Grid, I'm writing unit tests following the [official example](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/testing/).

But I got a error: `Property 'setValue' does not exist on type 'ICellEditor'. Did you mean 'getValue'?`

---

```
import { AgGridModule } from "@ag-grid-community/angular";
import { ColDef, ColumnApi, GridApi, GridOptions, GridReadyEvent, ICellEditor, TextCellEditor } from "@ag-grid-community/core";
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { EditorComponent } from "./editor.component";
import { ClientSideRowModelModule } from "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";


describe('EditorComponent', () => {
    let component: TestHostComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;

    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [AgGridModule, FormsModule],
            declarations: [TestHostComponent]
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    }))

    it('cell should be editable and editor component usable', () => {
        // Setup template bindings and run ngOInit. This causes the <ag-grid-angular> component to be created.
        // As part of the creation the grid apis will be attached to the gridOptions property.
        fixture.detectChanges();

        // we use the API to start and stop editing - in a real e2e test we could actually double click on the cell etc
        component.gridOptions.api?.startEditingCell({
            rowIndex: 0,
            colKey: 'raw'
        });

        const instances: ICellEditor[] = component.gridOptions.api!.getCellEditorInstances();
        expect(instances.length).toEqual(1);

        const editorComponent = instances[0];
        editorComponent.setValue(100); // error: Property 'setValue' does not exist on type 'ICellEditor'. Did you mean 'getValue'?

        // component.api.stopEditing();

        // const appElement = fixture.nativeElement;
        // const cellElements = appElement.querySelectorAll('.ag-cell-value');
        // expect(cellElements.length).toEqual(3);
        // expect(cellElements[0].textContent).toEqual("Test Name");
        // expect(cellElements[1].textContent).toEqual("100");
        // expect(cellElements[2].textContent).toEqual("200");
    });

});


@Component({
    template:
        `<div>
            <ag-grid-angular
                style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" class="ag-theme-alpine"
                [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                [rowData]="rowData"
                [stopEditingWhenCellsLoseFocus]="false"
                [components]="components"
                [modules]="modules"
                [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
            </ag-grid-angular>
        </div>`
})
class TestHostComponent {
    rowData: any[] = [{ name: 'Test Name', raw: 42, number: 84 }];
    modules = [ClientSideRowModelModule];
    columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
        { field: "name" },
        { field: "raw", colId: "raw", headerName: "Raw Number", editable: true, cellRenderer: EditorComponent },
        { field: "number", colId: "renderer", headerName: "Renderer Value" }
    ];

    components = {

    };

    gridOptions: GridOptions = {

    }

    api!: GridApi;
    columnApi!: ColumnApi;

    public onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
        this.api = params.api;
        this.columnApi = params.columnApi;
    }
}
```

I checked the source code for type `ICellEditor`, It really doesn't have a setValue method

So, I want to know the reason, is it because the local version(27.3) doesn't match the official website?

Is there any other way to create unit tests for CellEditor components?

---

```
export interface ICellEditor {
    /**
     * Return the final value - called by the grid once after editing is complete
     */
    getValue(): any;
    /** Gets called once after initialised. If you return true, the editor will
     * appear in a popup, so is not constrained to the boundaries of the cell.
     * This is great if you want to, for example, provide you own custom dropdown list
     * for selection. Default is false (ie if you don't provide the method).
     */
    isPopup?(): boolean;
    /** Gets called once, only if isPopup() returns true. Return "over" if the popup
     * should cover the cell, or "under" if it should be positioned below leaving the
     * cell value visible. If this method is not present, the default is "over".
     */
    getPopupPosition?(): string | undefined;
    /** Gets called once after initialised. If you return true, the editor will not be
     * used and the grid will continue editing. Use this to make a decision on editing
     * inside the init() function, eg maybe you want to only start editing if the user
     * hits a numeric key, but not a letter, if the editor is for numbers.
     */
    isCancelBeforeStart?(): boolean;
    /** Gets called once after editing is complete. If your return true, then the new
     * value will not be used. The editing will have no impact on the record. Use this
     * if you do not want a new value from your gui, i.e. you want to cancel the editing.
     */
    isCancelAfterEnd?(): boolean;
    /**
     * If doing full line edit, then gets called when focus should be put into the editor
     */
    focusIn?(): void;
    /**
     * If doing full line edit, then gets called when focus is leaving the editor
     */
    focusOut?(): void;
    /**
     * A hook to perform any necessary operation just after the GUI for this component has been rendered on the screen.
     * This method is called each time the edit component is activated.
     * This is useful for any logic that requires attachment before executing, such as putting focus on a particular DOM element.
     */
    afterGuiAttached?(): void;
}
```